# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'autoplay' was never awaited

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import json
import os
import random
from pathlib import Path

import discord
import requests
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from youtubesearchpython import SearchVideos
from pytube import YouTube

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
PREFIX = os.getenv('DISCORD_PREFIX')
YOUTUBE_KEY = os.getenv('YOUTUBE_API1')
OWNER_ID = os.getenv('OWNER_ID')
CACHE_SIZE = os.getenv('CACHE_SIZE')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX,intents=intents)
is_playing = True
is_skipping = False
is_recommended = False
is_bot_locked = False
is_repeat_mode = False
playlist = []
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
current_playing_song = ""
current_song_data = []
is_pinging = True


async def autoplay(ctx):
    global is_skipping, current_playing_song, current_song_data
    while is_playing:
        if playlist:
            voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            current_song_data = playlist.pop()
            current_playing_song = current_song_data[0]
            await ctx.channel.send('Now playing ' + current_song_data[1])
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}) as ydl:
                video = ydl.extract_info(current_song_data[1], download=False)
            await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=video['title'], url=current_song_data[1]))
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f'audio_cache/{current_song_data[0]}.webm'))
            while voice.is_playing() or voice.is_paused():
                if is_skipping:
                    is_skipping = False
                    voice.stop()
                    break
                else:
                    await asyncio.sleep(.5)
        else:
            if is_repeat_mode:
                playlist.append(current_song_data)
            elif is_recommended:
                video_id = current_playing_song if current_playing_song else get_random_song()[-1]
                await get_recommended_song(ctx, video_id)
            else:
                audio = get_random_song()
                await download_file(ctx.channel, audio[0], audio[1])


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='ping', help='Ping your bot')
async def ping(ctx):
    global is_pinging
    await ctx.send(f'Latency is {round(bot.latency * 100)}ms')


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='summon', help='Connect the bot to voice channel')
async def summon(ctx):
    global is_playing
    if not await check_if_user_connected(ctx):
        return

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice:
        await ctx.channel.send('Bot is already connected to voice channel')
        return

    is_playing = True
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    loop.create_task(autoplay(ctx))
    await ctx.channel.send(
        f"Connected to {channel}, Playing in {'Recommendation' if is_recommended else 'Auto Playlist'} mode.")


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'play'], help='play music')
async def play_music(ctx, *, arg):
    voice = await get_bot_voice(ctx)
    if not voice:
        return

    await search_video(ctx.channel, arg)


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['s', 'skip'], help='Skip music')
async def skip_music(ctx):
    global is_skipping

    voice = await get_bot_voice(ctx)
    if not voice:
        return

    if is_playing:
        await ctx.channel.send('Skipping the song')
        is_skipping = True
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Nothing is playing')


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='disconnect', help='Disconnect the bot')
async def disconnect(ctx):
    global is_playing

    voice = await get_bot_voice(ctx)
    if not voice:
        return

    is_playing = False
    await ctx.channel.send('Bye Bye')
    await voice.disconnect()


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['sw', 'switch'], help='Switch play mode')
async def switch_mode(ctx):
    global is_recommended
    is_recommended = not is_recommended
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Autoplay mode changed to {'Recommended' if is_recommended else 'Autoplaylist'}")


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='lock', help='Lock the bot')
async def lock(ctx):
    global is_bot_locked

    if str(ctx.author.id) == str(OWNER_ID):
        is_bot_locked = True


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='unlock', help='Unlock the bot')
async def unlock(ctx):
    global is_bot_locked

    if str(ctx.author.id) == str(OWNER_ID):
        is_bot_locked = False


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='pause', help='Pause music')
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = await get_bot_voice(ctx)
    if not voice:
        return

    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
        await ctx.channel.send('Paused')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Nothing is playing')


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='resume', help='Resume music')
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = await get_bot_voice(ctx)
    if not voice:
        return

    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
        await ctx.channel.send('Resuming the song')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Nothing is playing')


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='save', help='Save music to Autoplaylist')
async def save(ctx):
    voice = await get_bot_voice(ctx)
    if not voice:
        return

    song = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={current_playing_song}\n"

    if song in list(open('autoplaylist.txt')):
        await ctx.channel.send('This song is already in Autoplaylist')
    else:
        open('autoplaylist.txt', 'a').write(song)
        await ctx.channel.send('Song is added to Autoplaylist')


@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None and str(member.id) == str('756835280714989620'):
        await member.move_to(None)


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='remove', help='Remove music from Autoplaylist')
async def remove(ctx):
    voice = await get_bot_voice(ctx)
    if not voice:
        return

    song = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={current_playing_song}\n"

    songs = list(open('autoplaylist.txt'))
    if song in songs:
        songs.remove(song)
        open('autoplaylist.txt', 'w').write("".join(songs))
        await ctx.channel.send('Song is removed from Autoplaylist')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('This Song is not in Autoplaylist')


@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='repeat', help='Toggle repeat mode')
async def repeat(ctx):
    global is_repeat_mode

    if is_repeat_mode:
        is_repeat_mode = False
        await ctx.channel.send('Repeat mode OFF')
    else:
        is_repeat_mode = True
        await ctx.channel.send('Repeat mode ON')


async def check_if_user_connected(ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if not connected:
        await ctx.channel.send('You are not connected to any voice channel')
        return False
    return True


async def get_bot_voice(ctx):
    if is_bot_locked and str(ctx.author.id) != str(OWNER_ID):
        await ctx.channel.send('Bot is Locked, Ask an admin to unlock')
        return None

    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if not connected:
        await ctx.channel.send('You are not connected to any voice channel')
        return None

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice:
        await ctx.channel.send('Bot is not connected to any voice channel, Please summon the bot first.')
        return None
    return voice


async def search_video(channel, search):
    search = SearchVideos(search, offset=1, mode="list", max_results=1)

    if len(search.result()) != 1:
        await channel.send('Unable to find any Video')
    else:
        await channel.send('Added to stack ' + search.result()[0][3])
        await download_file(channel, search.result()[0][2], search.result()[0][1])


async def download_file(channel, url, key):
    file_path = f'audio_cache/{key}.webm'

    if Path(file_path).is_file():
        playlist.append([key, url])
        return

    try:
        clear_cache()
        yt = YouTube(url)
        yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(output_path='audio_cache', filename=f'{key}.webm')
        playlist.append([key, url])
    except Exception as e:
        await channel.send(str(e))


def clear_cache():
    try:
        path, v, files = next(os.walk("audio_cache"))
        if len(files) > int(CACHE_SIZE):
            song = random.choice(files)
            for music in playlist:
                if song.strip('.webm') == music[0]:
                    return
            os.remove(f"{path}/{song}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


async def get_recommended_song(ctx, key):
    global YOUTUBE_KEY
    audio = get_random_song()
    url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=" \
          f"{key}&type=video&key={YOUTUBE_KEY}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.ok:
        songs = json.loads(response.content)['items']
        if len(songs) > 1:
            songs.pop(0)
            video_id = random.choice(songs)['id']['videoId']
            audio = [f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}", video_id]
    else:
        if YOUTUBE_KEY is os.getenv('YOUTUBE_API1'):
            YOUTUBE_KEY = os.getenv('YOUTUBE_API2')
        else:
            YOUTUBE_KEY = os.getenv('YOUTUBE_API1')

    await download_file(ctx.channel, audio[0], audio[1])


def get_random_song():
    song = random.choice(list(open('autoplaylist.txt'))).strip('\n')
    return [song, song.split("=")[-1]]


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-21' coro=<autoplay() running at c:\Users\S1ncer3ly\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot-main\main.py:38>>
C:\Users\S1ncer3ly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py:675: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'autoplay' was never awaited

Im totally new into this thankyou

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

change the line `loop.create_task(autoplay(ctx))` to `await autoplay(ctx)`